# Media query with StyleSheet doesn't work in react-pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-pdf

I have attempted to let 'react-pdf' to change its size by using media query.

I do understand that:

```
// when I put mouse cursor on <Document>, it displays: 
(alias) class Document import Document

            <div className="pdf">
              <Document file={HomePDF}>
                <Page scale={1.5} pageNumber={1} />
              </Document>
            </div>
```

is how to adjust the scale in general.

But with media query on css,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .home-text {
        width: 400px;
    }

    .pdf {
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```

Despite reading the document, I can't get an idea.
https://react-pdf.org/styling#media-queries

The size of pdf displayed on the page does not take effect.
With this error message:

```
"Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/pages/Home/Home.js 12:15-32

export 'StyleSheet' (imported as 'StyleSheet') was not found in 'react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack5' (possible exports: Document, Outline, Page, pdfjs)"
```

I feel like I lost the way. What should I do to change the size of this react-pdf outcome other than the hook? Or is there a way I can do?

```
// Home.js
import React from "react";
import "./Home.css";

// pdf
import React from "react";
import "./Home.css";

// pdf
import { Document, Page } from "react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack5";
import { StyleSheet } from "@react-pdf/render";
import HomePDF from "../../pdf/resume.pdf";

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  section: {
    width: 200,
    "@media max-width: 400": {
      width: 300,
    },
    "@media orientation: landscape": {
      width: 400,
    },
  },
});

function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="home-wrapper">
        {/* layer very back */}
        <div className="home-content">
          <div className="home-text">
            {/* profile picture, box */}
            <img
              className="profile"
              src={require("../../images/me-photo.jpg")}
            />
            <hr />
            {/* pdf */}
            <div className="pdf">
              <Document file={HomePDF}>
                {/* <Page scale={1.5} pageNumber={1} /> */}
                <Page size="A4" style={styles.page} />
              </Document>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Ok, this is not the best solution but let me share how I solved this. Use 'max-width and max-height'.